# strtotime() function working inconsistently when the string is returned by substr()

Tags: php, strtotime, substr

I'm using `substr()` to get a date string from a long text, date found using the `preg_match()` function.
I then use `strtotime()` to convert this string to an epoch timestamp, because I need to do a comparison with another date already in this format.

It seems to work quite inconsistently, and after some testing, I can't seem to find the source of the bug. While the date string returned by `substr()` is always correct, the `strtotime()` function doesn't always work. Note that the `substr()` is extracted from a larger string, itself coming from a database. Could the problem come from hidden character, or formatting ?

```
<?php
$DateString = substr($text, $matches[sizeof($matches) - 1][1] - 22, 17); //$DateString = the expected '2018-03-21 08:04' when echo
$DateString_hardcoded = '2018-03-21 08:04';

$DateEpoch = strtotime($DateString); //$DateEpoch is null
$DateEpoch_hardcoded = strtotime($DateString_hardcoded); //$DateEpoch_hardcoded return the expected 1521619440
?>
```

What I don't understand is that sometimes, the string date gets converted correctly, using the exact same code. For instance, when

```
substr($text, $matches[sizeof($matches) - 1][1] - 22, 17) = '2010-08-23 16:10', $DateEpoch = 1282579800
```

as expected.

Comment: Can you post samples so we can actually help give you an answer.

Comment: I failed the formatting of the code sample. Edited now.

Comment: What does `$matches` and `$text` look like?

Comment: @waterloomatt $matches is the array of results, assigned by preg_match(), with the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag.
$text is, for instance : 
Action assigned to . 
[2010-08-23 16:10 UTC] State changed to Completed by Alfio Mantineo.

Comment: I would look at using DateTime instead of strtotime. Example: echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i',$DateString_hardcoded)->format('U'); Date time is a much better choice and more reliable.

Comment: @Lulceltech I tried to use DateTime, but without success. echo (preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $DateString )); shows 2007-09-23 14:11, but DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i',$DateString_hardcoded)->format('U'); crashes because createFromFormat returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just don't know how to count, and I had to do -21 and not - 22 for the starting index for substr().
I ended up with a fine date, but with blank space at the very beginning. I don't know why it didn't show up when echo.
Solved.

Comment: Hint, when echoing something and you want to make sure there are no leading and trailing spaces (or other things) surround the output with a *. Something along the lines of `echo '*' . $stringtotest . '*';`.